# Android Emulator dicsonnected on incoming call

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation

I have `Android 4.4.2 (API 19)` with latest Eclipse versions on windows 7, but when I launch `AVD` and try to place call from `DDMS`, my emulator disconnects from `DDMS`. Already tried following:

1. `adb reset` to connect back, emulator still disconnects again if I try to place call.
2. cleared my `AVD cache`
3. restarted eclipse multiple time
4. removed and recreated my `AVD`
5. Tried placing call through `telnet`

None of above solve the issue.

From my search on stackoverflow I did not received any reply which has solved this issue. Do let me know if anyone has a solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the Intel emulator? If not, I'd try that first if I were you. Also, does logcat give you any error message before it gets disconnected?

Comment: I am using ARM, its an intel laptop but no hardware virtulization is enabled.

Comment: Also Log cat does not shows any error, but gives following output:

Answer (score 0):

Logcat output is as follows:

```
07-31 11:58:33.240: D/MobileDataStateTracker(385): default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
07-31 11:58:46.460: D/MobileDataStateTracker(385): default: Broadcast received: android.intent.action.ANY_DATA_STATE apnType=default
07-31 11:58:46.460: D/MobileDataStateTracker(385): default: Received state=SUSPENDED, old=CONNECTED, reason=2GVoiceCallStarted
07-31 11:58:46.460: D/MobileDataStateTracker(385): default: setDetailed state, old =CONNECTED and new state=SUSPENDED
07-31 11:58:46.470: D/ConnectivityService(385): ConnectivityChange for mobile: SUSPENDED/SUSPENDED
07-31 11:58:46.470: D/ConnectivityService(385): tryFailover: set mActiveDefaultNetwork=-1, prevNetType=0
07-31 11:58:46.470: D/ConnectivityService(385): Attempting to switch to wifi
07-31 11:58:46.530: D/MobileDataStateTracker(385): fota: Broadcast received: android.intent.action.ANY_DATA_STATE apnType=fota
07-31 11:58:46.540: D/MobileDataStateTracker(385): fota: Received state=DISCONNECTED, old=DISCONNECTED, reason=2GVoiceCallStarted
07-31 11:58:46.580: D/MobileDataStateTracker(385): ia: Broadcast received: android.intent.action.ANY_DATA_STATE apnType=ia
07-31 11:58:46.610: D/MobileDataStateTracker(385): ia: Received state=DISCONNECTED, old=DISCONNECTED, reason=2GVoiceCallStarted
07-31 11:58:46.610: D/MobileDataStateTracker(385): supl: Broadcast received: android.intent.action.ANY_DATA_STATE apnType=supl
07-31 11:58:46.630: D/MobileDataStateTracker(385): supl: Received state=DISCONNECTED, old=DISCONNECTED, reason=2GVoiceCallStarted
07-31 11:58:46.630: D/MobileDataStateTracker(385): hipri: Broadcast received: android.intent.action.ANY_DATA_STATE apnType=hipri
07-31 11:58:46.680: D/MobileDataStateTracker(385): hipri: Received state=DISCONNECTED, old=DISCONNECTED, reason=2GVoiceCallStarted
07-31 11:58:46.680: D/MobileDataStateTracker(385): ims: Broadcast received: android.intent.action.ANY_DATA_STATE apnType=ims
07-31 11:58:46.690: D/MobileDataStateTracker(385): ims: Received state=DISCONNECTED, old=DISCONNECTED, reason=2GVoiceCallStarted
07-31 11:58:46.690: D/MobileDataStateTracker(385): mms: Broadcast received: android.intent.action.ANY_DATA_STATE apnType=mms
07-31 11:58:46.710: D/MobileDataStateTracker(385): mms: Received state=DISCONNECTED, old=DISCONNECTED, reason=2GVoiceCallStarted
07-31 11:58:46.710: D/MobileDataStateTracker(385): cbs: Broadcast received: android.intent.action.ANY_DATA_STATE apnType=cbs
07-31 11:58:46.720: D/CallNotifier(617): RINGING... (new)
07-31 11:58:46.720: D/CallNotifier(617): onNewRingingConnection(): state = RINGING, conn = {  incoming: true state: INCOMING post dial state: NOT_STARTED }
07-31 11:58:46.760: D/CallNotifier(617): SignalInfoTonePlayer.run(toneId = 98)...
07-31 11:58:46.760: D/NetUtils(385): android_net_utils_resetConnections in env=0xb8968b00 clazz=0xbdf00001 iface=eth0 mask=0x3
07-31 11:58:46.760: D/ConnectivityService(385): resetConnections(eth0, 3)
07-31 11:58:46.770: D/MobileDataStateTracker(385): cbs: Received state=DISCONNECTED, old=DISCONNECTED, reason=2GVoiceCallStarted
: E/(): Device disconnected
```